# Device Endpoint - Brand Name Mismatch

Tags: openfda

When we Query Maude Website for Report Number "2024168-2020-03898", the brand name is displayed as “ABSORB BIORESORBABLE VASCULAR SCAFFOLD SYSTEM”.

However, when we use the device endpoint and query the same report (URL below), the output brand_name is only “ABSORB”.

URL :
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=report_number:%222024168-2020-03898%22

Screenshots :

Website Search Query + Result:
[image]

API:

[image]

URL: https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=report_number:%222024168-2020-03898%22

1. Will this be corrected or it will be like this and we continue to use it like this?
2. Is there a single place where similar data issues are reported?

Note: We got this Report Number when we tried to search for something else and there probably are many more such instances which have data mismatches between Website and API.

Comment: Updated Device Event dataset should go out very shortly with a fix to this and many similar issues. I will post back once it's out (most likely on Monday).

Answer (score 0):

The Device Event dataset in openFDA has been updated and this issue has been resolved.

https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues is the best place to report issues with openFDA to the development team.